# best use of MID and INSTR in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have a string that looks like this

> "Patient Name, Doc Name, Patient ID, something else"

i want to extract each one of these and put it in a variable. such that var1 will equal "Patient Name" var2 will equal "Doc name" etc.. using instr and mid. what is the best way to do it?

Comment: The "best use of Mid and Instr in vb.net" is NONE. Don't use them. EVER. Use .Substring(), .IndexOf(), and their kin instead.

Comment: the thing is i dont think i will switch because i'm so used to mid and instr and they are simple to use!

Comment: Joel is correct.  You will get a performance hit for using mid & instr

Comment: christian, not really so much. there arent too many programs written in vb.net that make such great use of mid and instr that it would make any difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do it is using the Split function - here's some vba code to do it:

```
Dim txt as String = "Patient Name, Doc Name, Patient ID, something else"
Dim x as Variant
Dim i as Long

x = Split(txt, ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(x)
   Debug.Print x(i)
Next i
```

And in VB.Net:

```
Dim txt as String = "Patient Name, Doc Name, Patient ID, something else"
Dim split As String() = txt.Split(",")
    For Each s As String In  split
        If s.Trim() <> "" Then
            Console.WriteLine(s)
        End If
    Next s
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the string methods that are part of the .NET framework instead of the legacy VB functions.

`String.Split()` will get you 99% of the way to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason for avoiding the well-known methods from the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings module (for example, InStr and Mid) may be if you are used to the methods from System.String from a C# background or you want to make your solution highly portable (so you can run it also on Mono).

Using these methods may be confusing for C# programmers (because the index of the first character is 1, not 0) but they really have one great advantage: they obbey the Option Compare setting! You may notice that, if you use the default Option Compare Binary, certain methods are even faster than their counterparts from the System.String class. This is because in this case they perform a binary compare while the other methods will have to perform a culture sensitive compare.

Last but not least, all these methods will not throw exceptions if you pass Nothing (null) to them, because in VB.NET Nothing is the equivalent of an empty string. Microsoft shows now intent to drop these functions in future releases of the .NET platform (although no one can ever be sure about anything surviving another release).

Take a good look at the merrits and benefits of both the 'inherent' string functions of VB.NET and those provided by the System.String class. For a VB.NET programmer with a Visual Basic background, using these 'inherent' functions may be a natural way to solve your problems, and generally you don't have to worry about their performance that much.